# Pass function pointer in parameter to pthread_create, (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, pthreads

Here is a minimal example which illustrates my problem

**test.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define CORES 8

pthread_t threads [ CORES ];
int threadRet [ CORES ];

void foo ()
{
   printf ("BlahBlahBlah\n" );
}

void distribute ( void ( *f )() )
{
   int i;

   for ( i = 0; i < CORES; i++ )
   {
      threadRet [ i ] = pthread_create ( &threads [ i ], NULL, f, NULL );
   }
   for ( i = 0; i < CORES; i++ )
   {
      pthread_join ( threads [ i ], NULL );
   }
}

int main ()
{
   distribute ( &foo );
   return 0;
}
```

**Vim/gcc output**:

```
test.c:20|11| warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225|12| note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)()’
```

What `*`/`&` do I need to add/remove to pass `foo` to `distribute` which then passes it to a thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void *foo (void *x)
{
   printf ("BlahBlahBlah\n" );
}

void distribute ( void * (*f)(void *) ) {
  /* code */
}
```

should do the trick

because the prototype is:

```
extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
                           __const pthread_attr_t *__restrict __attr,
                           void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
                           void *__restrict __arg) __THROW __nonnull ((1, 3));
```

Answer (score 3):

The minimum recommended changes are:

```
void *foo(void *unused)
{
    printf("BlahBlahBlah\n");
    return 0;
}

void distribute(void *(*f)(void *))
{
    ...as before...
}
```

The [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) function wants a pointer to a function that takes a `void *` argument and returns a `void *` result (though you haven't got to that error yet).  So, pass it a pointer to that type of function by making `foo()` into a function that takes a `void *` argument and returns a `void *` result.  And, for what it's worth, you can almost certainly make `foo()` into a static function since it is unlikely you will call it directly from outside this file.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't follow

Comment: @puk: The thread start routine must take a `void *` as a parameter and also must return a `void *`. You can't cast around that requirement. To call `pthread_create`, that's the type of function you need to have because that's the only type of function it can call.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: yup - fixed that while you were commenting (though I remembered about the return type after I'd posted the original version of the answer).  Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Classic SO "Post first.Edit later"

Comment: @puk: Yes - tied with faulty memory about the return type because I was misled by your attempt to provide a function to be called.  It was fixed pretty quickly, I think.  Judging by the comment time stamps, within 3 minutes.

Comment: @puk: I was also misled by the formatting of the error message - some of the stars in the type were treated as 'change to italic' by the SO Markdown system.

Answer (score 0):

This page seems to explain it quite well: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fusers_14.htm;

Often IBM documentation is very good, keep an eye on those ibm links when they show up ;).

So, apparently you need a function pointer taking a void pointer in its argument. Try

```
void distribute ( void *( *f )(void *) ) {...}
```

You will probably also need to change your definition of foo though. See the following tutorial for function pointers: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html. Note: I haven't tested it myself, so no guarantees whether it will work - but I hope it at least points you in the right directions ;).